# Identify this story about cosmic entities please

Tags: story-identification, space

This story was written long ago. It would be less than 250 pages. The story was about a cosmic entity not unlike a star, but these guys weren't stars or even black holes. They were conscious and mobile, and to be quite frank solar systems were just toys and playthings to be made, watched and then knocked apart when you got bored of them. The time frames in this story were on the order of 100's of millions of years per chapter in the life of this *little* fellow.

As this one cosmic entity got *bored* or *disenchanted* with the status quo of all cosmic life, he decided to take a trip across the void and left the realm of stars and galaxies, and spend billions of years just pushing forward until eventually he started to see the light of another realm ahead. He plunged headlong into this universe, and explored until he discovered a *girl* cosmic entity.

My synopsis of this story is absolutely horrid, but it's the best I can do from what I remember, and quite frankly the story was written pretty ambiguously anyway. If you can help identify this story for me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think the duplicate is pointing the wrong way:  that question is _way_ better, and we can fix the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost certainly "Into the Darkness" written by [Ross Rocklynne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross_Rocklynne), initially published in *Astonishing Stories* in June of 1940, and collected elsewhere, as in *The Golden Years of Science Fiction* Volume 2, edited by [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov).

The story is much as you describe, with the main character—a being named "Darkness"—being larger than star-size, and existing on a much longer time scale than human, who is capable of impelling himself around the universe. He eventually grows bored with playing with the other such beings by slinging planets around, and eventually sets out to cross a great void where he meets a female [Aside: interesting that male/female sex was imputed to creatures of such cosmic scale!], mates with her, and discovers that while females can breed thrice before dying, males can breed only once. His dying act is to disperse protoplasmic parts of himself to a small planet, third from the star, near a spiral galactic rim.

Comment: Thanks, those additional details definately ring a bell. I was lucky enough to own the original book it was printed in. One of my friends at the time was an archeologist and antique book dealer and it was something he gave me. Unfortunately I lost a great many of those antique books due to a past marital situation. It's something I would like to share with my family.

Comment: I looked this up and it looks like it may actually be called "People of the Darkness: A Novel of Living Nebulae". Again thanks.

Comment: @Escoce Not sure about it's original publication name in *Astonishing Stories*, but in the *The Golden Years of Science Fiction* Volume 2 (which I have), it is collected as "Into the Darkness".

Comment: If the [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?251694) can be believed, it was "Into the Darkness" in the June 1940 *Astonishing Stories*. the first story in Ross Rocklynne's [*Darkness* series](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?27150), collected as *The Sun Destroyers* in an [Ace Double](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?1494) with Edmond Hamilton's *A Yank at Valhalla*.